# jQuery click event when triggered programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I have a link with an inline onclick event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="somefunction();">click</a>
```

I registered an additional function on the onclick event:

```
jQuery("#addMoreOptions").live('click',function(){
        console.log('clicked');
    });
```

Which works fine when I click on the link on the browser, but not when I simulate programmatically:

```
jQuery("#addMoreOptions").click();
```

The programatical version triggers the inline event but not the "live" one.

When you have multiple functions attached to an event, what order does it use?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mattlunn/zG9Jw/. What version of jQuery are you using/ can you produce a fiddle where this breaks/ what browser are you using?

Comment: not getting what you are saying...what do you mean by simulate programmatically ?

Comment: The fact that you're registering the event with `.live` is making me think that when you issue the `.click()` the element doesnt exist yet.

Comment: You're right your example works. I am using Chrome, latest version of jQuery. I will look more into and get back.

Comment: I agree with @Jamiec, is the element loaded dynamically? if not, just for fun. add a delay before you fire the click event.

Comment: I edited my question to add some details. I will look into the "live" issue

Comment: Ah with your update, the `.click()` is being called before the event has been subscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is caused by the order of things happening.

If you look at [this live example](http://jsfiddle.net/vyuV4/) you'll see everything works as expected. This is because the event is registered, and then called. The code looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   

    jQuery("#addMoreOptions").live('click',function(){
        console.log('clicked');
    });

     $('#addMoreOptions').click();      

});

function somefunction()
{
 alert("clicked");   
}
```

When the page loads, you get an `alert` and a `console.log`.

Now with the very small change of putting the `$('#addMoreOptions').click();` before registering the event as in [this live example](http://jsfiddle.net/ERRZv/) you only get the `alert` from the inline function.

For reference the code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
     $('#addMoreOptions').click();  

    jQuery("#addMoreOptions").live('click',function(){
        console.log('clicked');
    });   

});

function somefunction()
{
 alert("clicked");   
}
```

Comment: I removed the "inline" code and moved it to the live() call, so I have more control over the order of things. It fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of triggering a click event would be to use the .trigger() function:

```
jQuery('#addMoreOptions').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Considering all `click()` does is call `trigger('click')` [behind the scenes](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.3/src/event.js#L1177), this will make no difference.

Comment: There's no difference, the problem may lay in the live function not binding the event before it's called.